# How to create autoreply with number of unread mails in inbox using Outlook VBA?

Tags: vba, email, outlook, outlook-2016

I am trying to trigger a script with rules to send an autoreply.

"Hi thanks for your mail, your mail has been placed in a queue there are **XX** number of e-mails in front of you, we will answer as soon as possible."

The XX should be the number of unread e-mails.

I found [outlook automated reply with unread message count](https://superuser.com/questions/392482/outlook-automated-reply-with-unread-message-count):

```vb
Private Sub myOlItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

End Sub

Sub AutoResponse(objmsg As Outlook.MailItem)

    ' define my reply message
    Dim objReply As MailItem
    ' let's get ourselves the inbox!
    Dim inbox As MAPIFolder
    Set inbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI"). _
    GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    ' Let's get this reply going!
    Set objReply = objmsg.Reply
    ' Subject Re: their subject. Standard
    objReply.Subject = "Re: " & objReply.Subject
    ' Body - you define this, use the variable for the unread count in inbox
    objReply.Body = "Your email has been received. I currently have " & inbox.UnReadItemCount & " unread emails in my inbox and I will get yours as soon as I can"

    ' Send this thing!
    objReply.Send
    ' Reset
    Set objReply = Nothing

End Sub
```

It doesn't work.

I am on Outlook 2016, with an exchange mail server.

Comment: Is your macro setting okay to allow macro to run?

Comment: Hi guys. Macro settings allowing everything. Does it makes any difference that I am on an exchange mailbox, and the code dims the inbox as a mapi folder? That's the only reason I can think of.

Comment: if anyone have issues doing this i replaced: AutoResponse Items End If with AutoResponse Item End If

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Your **[Items.ItemAdd Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx)** is not set correctly, Try the flowing code without Outlook rule, Make sure to restart your Outlook*

```
Private WithEvents Items As Outlook.Items

Private Sub Application_Startup()
    Dim olNs As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Inbox  As Outlook.MAPIFolder

    Set olNs = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set Inbox = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set Items = Inbox.Items
End Sub

Private Sub Items_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)

    If TypeOf Item Is Outlook.mailitem Then
        AutoResponse Items
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub AutoResponse(Item As Outlook.mailitem)
    Dim Reply As Outlook.mailitem ' Reply msg
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.MAPIFolder ' Inbox

    Set Inbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI") _
                .GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)

    ' Let's get this reply going!
    Set Reply = Item.Reply
    ' Subject Re: their subject. Standard
    Reply.subject = Reply.subject

    ' Body - you define this, use the variable for the unread count in inbox
    Reply.HTMLBody = "Your email has been received. I currently have " & _
                      Inbox.UnReadItemCount & _
              " unread emails in my inbox and I will get yours as soon as I can"

    ' Send this thing!
    Reply.Send
    ' Reset
    Set Reply = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Just make sure that you drop the "S" in AutoResponse Items or it will continue to error.  Additionally, if you e-mail yourself (as I do sometimes to keep up with work) the script will continue to reply to itself indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a rule in Outlook manually and assign the VBA macro sub (`AutoResponse`) to the rule. Only then you will get the code running.

As a possible workaround you can handle the [NewMailEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff863686.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) event of the Application which is fired when a new item is received in the Inbox. The event fires when a new message arrives in the Inbox and before client rule processing occurs. You can use the Entry ID returned in the EntryIDCollection array to call the [NameSpace.GetItemFromID](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869893.aspx) method and process the item. See [Outlook's Rules and Alerts: Run a Script](https://www.slipstick.com/outlook/rules/outlooks-rules-and-alerts-run-a-script/) for more information.

For users with an Exchange Server account (non-Cached Exchange Mode or Cached Exchange Mode), the event will fire only for messages that arrive at the server after Outlook has started. The event will not fire for messages that are synchronized in Cached Exchange Mode immediately after Outlook starts, nor for messages that are already on the server when Outlook starts in non-Cached Exchange Mode.

Comment: Hi Eugene. Thanks for the help. I did the rule, and I tried to test the code, by sending mail according to the rule. The code did not trigger. I thought that it is something to do with the Dim inbox As MAPIFolder
    Set inbox = Application.GetNamespace("MAPI"). _

Comment: Try to run the code under the debugger and see which line of code fails.